# Make dropdown selected using option text (not using value) in select2

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-select2

I have dropdown using select2 as follows:

```
<select class=".select2" id="sel">
    <option  value="1">Some Text</option>
    <option   value="2">Other Text</option>
     <option  value="3">best Text</option>
</select>
```

What I need to make default selection as a particular option , suppose it is second option so I do as follows:

```
$("#sel").select2("val","2");
```

It is working fine. What I need is I want to make the option selected only by using the text value, ie, something like that

```
 $("#sel").select2("text","Other Text");
```

please check fiddle: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n4n5Y/168/)

Please guide me how can I achieve this without using value and only text of option?

Comment: But your fiddle is not working

Comment: let me check buddy i will update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger a change in value, append `.trigger("change")` to your script as below.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n4n5Y/178/)

`$("#sel option:contains(Other Text)").attr('selected', true).trigger("change");`

or just append `.change()`

[JSFIDDLE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/n4n5Y/179/)

`$("#sel option:contains(Other Text)").attr('selected', true).change();`

Comment: Thanks buddy this is what I am looking for.

Comment: great. glad to help. use one of the options above, second one is simpler in syntax but basically does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
var selectedText = 'Other Text';
    $('#sel option').map(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == selectedText) return this;
    }).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can change value using MVC model variable string**
`

```
function changeunloadingArea()
{
let $element = $("#unloadingareaselectlists");
let val = $element.find("option:contains(@Model.UnloadingArea)").val();
$element.val(val).trigger('change.select2');

};
```

`